# preventDefault works for one form but not the other form in the same modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, forms

when user clicks on the link a form opens up (i am using bootstrap Modal with form init), on submit new record gets created and added onto the page (all with jquery and ajax).

If user clicks on the newly added item, the same form will open up, ajax will get the data and pre-populate the form. But this time jquery will also create a new form with Delete button.

But when I click the Delete button, the form will make a full (non-ajax) request and item will be deleted.

Not sure why for the Create action preventDefault works (stops form for making full POST request), but when I click on Delete button/form, it makes a full request.

Both event handlers are in the same anonymous function.
Below is the jQuery/javascript that handle Submit event:

```
     // save form
form.on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.when(submitAjaxRequest(this)).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        if(update){
            $this.replaceWith(data)
        }else{
            addInput($this,data);
        }
        modal.modal('hide');
    });
});

// delete form
$('.panel-heading').on('submit','form #deleteForm',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.when(submitAjaxRequest(this)).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        $this.remove();
        modal.modal('hide');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your HTML, but if your're delete form is not inside the create form, I think the selector is wrong, so the event is never being triggered and I suppose your delete button is `type="submit"`, so you get the html submit. You have to remove the space...

```
$('.panel-heading').on('submit','form#deleteForm',function(event) {
....
```

I hope it helps